# Can I install an above-the-range microwave above an exhaust vent?

Tags: kitchens

So we recently purchased a house that doesn’t have a lot of counter space and we are wanting to install a microwave above the gas range. However , there is currently a through the wall exhaust fan right about the range on the wall. Are we able to still install the microwave above that fan? Or will it be a no go for above range microwave because of that fan? Thank you for your help! [image]

Comment: How is the fan's exhaust duct routed?

Comment: It’s ran right outside just straight back if that makes sense lol

Comment: I added a picture if that helps

Comment: There is not enough room above your range for a microwave ; unless you remove or reduce the cabinets.

Comment: Yea we would remove part of the cabinet to make it fit .

Comment: The picture really clarifies what you mean by a vent directly above the range.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common problem. So common that you can buy a microwave oven that has an exhaust fan on the bottom for use over a cooktop. Power and control of the fan is all part of the microwave. The typical term is "over the range microwave". Many companies make them, such as [this GE](https://amzn.to/2YAwOEM):

[image: GE JVM3160RFSS over the range microwave oven]

Key things to look for are:

- Microwave oven capacity
- Width - typical is 30"
- Speed (typically measured in CFM) of fan

and the tough one is to figure out if the exhaust vent location will work. Download the installation manual *before* you buy anything and see if everything will fit or what (if anything) you will need to change.

**Update based on picture:**

The picture shows an in-wall fan. I used to have one of those before I redid my kitchen many years ago. It looks like an original from the 1960s or earlier. This type of fan really does not do a very good job, because it is pulling air across instead of up. It is likely to pull more air from the rest of the kitchen than up from the cooktop. It *might* be effective if it is very high power, but I doubt that is the case.

Replacing the fan is a very good idea. But then you run into another problem. Even without including a microwave oven, a properly mounted exhaust fan would be relatively low over the cooktop. The cabinets above the cooktop should have been a bit shorter so that they could be mounted higher up on the wall to allow more room for a fan and (now) for a microwave oven.

What to do? When I redid my kitchen in a similar situation, I ended up, with the help of my electrician and his tools, knocking a new hole in the outer wall in the right place to install a new exhaust fan and I removed the old fan and covered up the hole. In your case, that will not be as easy a task. However, even without the fan problem (which is a real problem - you **need** a fan over a cooktop), there simply is not enough space to mount a microwave oven under that cabinet and still have a functional cooktop.

Comment: Many of the newer Range Microwave have an exhaust that does not need to be vented to the outside.

Comment: @Programmer66 That gets to the general question of "cooktop vent inside vs. outside". In general, the best is outside because that gets not just smoke & particulates (which can be handled reasonably well by a good filter) but also hot air and steam - which are, by far, best vented to the outside. In OP's case, they have a (presumably) functional exhaust vent, so it is a matter of retrofitting a microwave/exhaust fan to use the same vent. Switching to indoor venting would be a step backwards.

Comment: You are correct on the best exhaust if possible, but the vent hole in the wall as described would be where the microwave would be installed.  It is quite possible that the exhaust hole could be directly behind the microwave.  I am just providing an alternate solution if unable to hook up to existing vent pipes.  Even the last para of your ans states that it may not be possible to use the existing vent.  This is why this is a comment.

Comment: I added a picture if that helps

Comment: @Programmer66 an "_exhaust that does not need to be vented_" isn't really an exhaust, it's just a noisemaker that does nothing for safety or keeping your wall from getting greasy. pure evil.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a microwave with a built-in vent.   You already have a vent.

You could seal up the existing vent and use the duct-work for a microwave with a built-in vent...but that's a lot of work!

You could remove the cabinet doors, and the center brace, and put the microwave right on the existing shelf.  You'd just have to get power to it which you'll have to do whatever your choice.

Comment: Alright thank you! So you think it would be ok with that vent still there? It’s a brick home so it would be a lot a lot of work to close up that vent .

Comment: Sure, putting a microwave on the shelf above would have zero impact on the vent operation.   It might look weird...but to my eye it already does.  You might be able to find a small microwave that doesn't stick out over the shelf..